# Units in group rings.

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group of order $n$, and let $g_1 ... g_n$ be an enumeration of its elements. Let $a_1 ... a_n$ be a sequence of integers, such that $\sum a_i$ is relatively prime to $n$.

Consider $\mathbb{C}[G]$, the group ring of $G$ with complex coefficients. Does the element $\sum a_i g_i$ necessarily have to be a unit in the group ring? (I believe that the element does have to be a unit, and have a proof in the cyclic and abelian case, but was hoping for a reference in greater generality, at least in the case when $G$ is solvable.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is false for the cyclic group of order $6$. Let $g$ be a generator. Then $g^2-g+1$ acts by $0$ on the representations where $g$ acts by a primitive $6$-th root of $1$, and hence is not a unit in the group ring, but $1-1+1=1$ is relatively prime to $6$.

Generalizing this example, the statement is false for the cyclic group of order $pq$, with $p$ and $q$ two different primes. Let $g$ generate this group and let $\chi: G \to \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ be a character with $\chi(g)$ a primitive $pq$-th root of unity.  Let $\Phi_{pq}(x) = \sum c_k x^k$ be the $pq$-th cyclotomic polynomial. So the element $\Phi_{pq}(g)= \sum c_k g^k$ in $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ acts by $\Phi_{pq}(\chi(g)) =0$ on the representation $\chi$. Thus $\sum c_k g^k$ is not a unit. On the other hand, $\sum c_k = \Phi_{pq}(1)= 1$. (To compute the last, note that $\Phi_{pq}(x) = \frac{(x^{pq}-1)(x-1)}{(x^q-1)(x^p-1)}$ and take the limit as $x \to 1$.)

I claim further that, if $G$ has any element of non-prime-power order, then $G$ fails to have this condition. Let $g$ be an element of order $pq$ and let $\chi: \langle g \rangle \to \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ be an injective character. Let $V = \mathrm{Ind}_{\langle g \rangle}^G \chi$. Then $V$ restricted to $\langle g \rangle$ has $\chi$ as a summand, and this summand is in the kernel of $\Phi_{pq}(g)$ acting on $V$. So $\Phi_{pq}(g)$ acts non-injectively on a representation of $G$, and thus is not a unit.

So the only groups for which this might be right are groups where every element has prime power order. These were classified by [Higman](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-32.3.335), so you can dig into his paper if you care enough.

---

On the positive side, the statement is true whenever $G$ is a $p$-group. Let $\alpha = \sum c_g g \in \mathbb{Z}[G]$. I will show that the determinant of $\alpha$ acting on $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ is $\left( \sum c_g \right)^{|G|} \bmod p$, and hence is not $0$ if $\sum c_g \not \equiv 0 \bmod p$. Reducing $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ modulo $p$, we get an action of $\alpha$ on $\mathbb{F}_p[G]$. More generally, I claim that $\alpha$ acts on any $G$-representation $V$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ by $\left( \sum c_g \right)^{\dim V}$. This is simple: $V$ has a filtration whose associated graded is a $\dim V$-dimensional trivial representation. Passing to the associated graded doesn't change determinant, and $\alpha$ acts on the $1$-dimensional trivial representation by $\sum c_g$.

Comment: Alternatively, the product of this element with $(g + 1)(g^3 - 1)$ is $0$.  (That's probably effectively the same proof in a minor disguise.)

Comment: Maybe you’re missing some conditions in the edit? $S_3^{ab}\cong C_2$, whose order is not divisible by 3.

Comment: Thank you for the correction! Indeed, $S_3$ does seem to obey this condition.

Comment: Thanks very much for your extremely detailed response! 

Can I please be annoying and add the condition that $a_1, ... a_n$ is a sequence of non-negative integers? The argument I had in mind in the cyclic case was to construct a polynomial $f(x)$ with coefficients $a_i$ like the one you did ($g^2 - g + 1$), and you'd then have that $f(x)$ divides $g(x) = \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$. However, as $g(1) = n$ and $f(1)$ is relatively prime to $n$, this is a contradiction -- unless of course $f(1) = 1$ -- and the condition $a_i \geq 0$ deals with that case.

Comment: Also, is it ok if I add a note at the end of the original question to add in this condition, or should I just start a new post? I'm not sure what MO etiquette is.

Comment: You still lose. $(x^2-x+1) + (x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$ has nonnegative coefficients and acts by $0$ on the same representations as before. In general, replace all occurences of $\Phi_{pq}(g)$ above with $\Phi_{pq}(g) + N (1+x+\cdots + x^{pq})$ where $N$ is sufficiently large and divisible by $|G|$.

Comment: Regarding the ettiquette question, it is usually better to start a new question which people have put significant effort into the old one. But, in this case, the new condition doesn't help anyway.

Answer (score 9):

David Speyer's example shows that the answer is "no", in general, even in the cyclic case. However, here are a few general remarks about the case of finite Abelian groups.

Each linear character (ie, group homomorphism $G \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$), say $\lambda,$ extends by linearity to an algebra homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}G \to \mathbb{C}$ (which we call $\lambda^{+}$ here).

When $G$ is Abelian, an element $u \in \mathbb{C}G$ is a unit of $\mathbb{C}G$ if and only $\lambda^{+}(u) \neq 0$ for each linear character $\lambda$ of $G.$

In a positive direction, the answer to your question is positive when $G$ is a finite Abelian $p$-group. If $u = \sum_{i}a_{i}g_{i}$ with $p$ not dividing $\sum_{i}a_{i}$ (each $a_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}$), then 
for each linear character $\lambda$ of $G$, we have 
$\lambda^{+}(u) \in \mathbb{Z}[\eta]$, but $\lambda^{+}(u) \equiv \sum_{i} a_{i} \not \equiv 0$ (mod $\pi$), where $\pi$ is the unique prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\eta]$ containing $p$ ( $\eta$ being a primitive $p^{e}$-th root of unity where $G$ has exponent $p^{e}$). Then certainly $\lambda^{+}(u) \neq 0.$